# Opinion: Using SSL/HTTPS with Stripe

Tags: ssl, https, stripe-payments

I'm creating a web portal that will allow customers to login, modify data as well as create and update payment and subscription data.

I'm reading that the Stripe API and Stripe.js only works over SSL.

Would it be easier to:

- Keep my public site as http and once a user is logged in and authenticated switch over to https? (If this is possible).
- Make the entire site accessible by https?
- Not use stripe as all and use some other solution?
- I read in another stack overflow post that if u use Stripe.js then you don't have to worry about sending the request over ssl. (However i think this may be false).. any insight would help.

Comment: You should use HTTPS everywhere.

Comment: There is no excuse to not use SSL on pages that accept CC numbers, no matter how you process them, because attackers can modify your page to steal the number.

Comment: So the site before login should be SSL as well? I was reading that it can slow down web traffic.

Comment: @SLaks how would one go about making my website behave in this manner: If i go the the site its server over http, but once i login it redirects to a new page that is served only over SSL?

Comment: HTTPS is generally not too slow.

Comment: @SLaks so if a user types in www.site.com will it automatically convert the request to SSL? or if they use https://www.site.com?

Comment: Yes; you need to set up a redirect.